# Elasticsearch average over date histogram buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, facet, date-histogram

I've got a bunch of documents indexed in ElasticSearch, and I need to get the following data:

For each month, get the average number of documents **per working day of the month** (or if impossible, use 20 days as the default).

I already aggregated my data into months buckets using the `date histogram` aggregation. I tried to nest a `stats` bucket, but this aggregations uses data extracted from the document's field, not from the parent bucket.

Here is my query so far:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "docs_per_month": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "created_date",
                "interval": "month",
                "min_doc_count": 0
            }
            "aggs": {
                '???': '???'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**

To make my question clearer, what I need is:

- Get the total of numbers of documents created for the month (which is already done thanks to the `date_histogram` aggregation)
- Get the number of working days for the month
- Divide the first by the second.

---

Comment: Definitly need to update my profile…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically need is something like this (**which doesn't work, as it's not an available feature**):

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average": {
          "avg": {
            "script": "doc_count / 20"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work because there is not way of accessing the `doc_count` from the "parent" aggregation.

But, this will be possible in the 2.x branch of Elasticsearch and, at the moment, it's being actively developed: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110
This new feature will add a second layer of manipulation over the results (buckets) of an aggregation and it's not only your usecase, but many others.

Unless you want to try [some ideas out there](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4983#issuecomment-49109895) or perform your own calculations in your app, you need to wait for this feature.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone still interested, you can now do with with the `avg_bucket` aggregation. Its still a bit tricky, because you cannot simply run the `avg_bucket` on a `date_historgram` aggregation result, but with a secondary `value_count` aggregation with some unique value and it works fine :)

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "orders_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "orderedDate",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "amount": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "dateCreated"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "avg_daily_order": {
      "avg_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "orders_per_day>amount"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. It takes into account what can be done with respect to what they added in recent versions. It is now a more accurate answer than the others.

Comment: nice workaround, thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is a pretty convoluted solution and not really performant, using the following [`scripted_metric` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created_date",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_doc_per_biz_day": {
          "scripted_metric": {
            "init_script": "_agg.bizdays = []; _agg.allbizdays = [:]; start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0); now = new DateTime(); while (start < now) { def end = start.plusMonths(1); _agg.allbizdays[start.year + '_' + start.monthOfYear] = (start.toDate()..<end.toDate()).sum {(it.day != 6 && it.day != 0) ? 1 : 0 }; start = end; }",
            "map_script": "_agg.bizdays << _agg.allbizdays[doc. created_date.date.year+'_'+doc. created_date.date.monthOfYear]",
            "combine_script": "_agg.allbizdays = null; doc_count = 0; for (d in _agg.bizdays){ doc_count++ }; return doc_count / _agg.bizdays[0]",
            "reduce_script": "res = 0; for (a in _aggs) { res += a }; return res"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's detail each script below.

What I'm doing in `init_script` is creating a map of the number of business days for each month since 1970 and storing that in the `_agg.allbizdays` map.

```
_agg.bizdays = [];
_agg.allbizdays = [:]; 
start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0);
now = new DateTime();
while (start < now) { 
    def end = start.plusMonths(1);     
    _agg.allbizdays[start.year + '_' + start.monthOfYear] = (start.toDate()..<end.toDate()).sum {(it.day != 6 && it.day != 0) ? 1 : 0 }; 
    start = end; 
}
```

In `map_script`, I'm simply retrieving the number of weekdays for the month of each document;

```
_agg.bizdays << _agg.allbizdays[doc.created_date.date.year + '_' + doc. created_date.date.monthOfYear];
```

In `combine_script`, I'm summing up the average doc count for each shard

```
_agg.allbizdays = null;
doc_count = 0; 
for (d in _agg.bizdays){ doc_count++ }; 
return doc_count / _agg.bizdays[0];
```

And finally in `reduce_script`, I'm summing up the average doc count for each node:

```
res = 0; 
for (a in _aggs) { res += a }; 
return res
```

Again I think it's pretty convoluted and as Andrei rightly said it, it is probably better to wait for 2.0 to make it work the way it should, but in the meantime you have this solution, if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to exclude documents with timestamp on Saturday and Sunday, so you can exclude those documents in your query using a script

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek != 7 && doc['@timestamp'].date.dayOfWeek != 6"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "docs_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "created_date",
        "interval": "month",
        "min_doc_count": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs_per_day": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "created_date",
            "interval": "day",
            "min_doc_count": 0
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "docs_count": {
            "avg": {
              "field": ""
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You may not need the first aggregation by month, since you already have this information using day interval

BTW you need to make sure dynamic scripting is enabled by adding this to your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Or add a groovy script under /config/scripts and use a filtered query with a script in filter

Comment: Thx for your answer. However, I don't want to count only the documents created on working days, I need to count all the documents for the month (which I already did), and then divide by the number of working days. What I don't know is how do I count that number (working days in the month).

Comment: I will edit my question, because I realize it's maybe misleading.

Comment: Although it might not help the OP precisely, it did help me finding the proper syntax for using a histogram in combination with aggregations. Thanks!